# How to get an array from ajax call to display proper results with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I am pulling some values using AJAX and PHP and then displaying them. This is just an upvote system. What I am wondering is how can I display the results properly so that the value gets updated client side. Here is an example of code and what it does below.

Here is the AJAX portion that gets the array response from the PHP file in json.

```
function upVoteIncrementValue(postID){
event.preventDefault();
//var upVoteIncrement   = $("#upVoteIncrement").val();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "voting.php",
        data:  {
            "upVoteIncrement": postID,
            },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response){
                var response = $.trim(response);
                if(response){
                    //$('#voteCount').html(response);
                      $('#voteCount-' + postID).html(response); //This is the working update
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Then here is the code that displays the results:

```
public function forumview($query){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
        foreach($results as $row){

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="color: #333;"><span class="pull-right">';

            if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){

                    echo '<a href="#" class="upVoteArrow" onclick="upVoteIncrementValue('.$row['topic_id'].');"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a> ';                   

            }else{

                echo '<a href="#" id="loginForm" class="upVoteArrow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a> ';

            }
           //This is the part that displays the result but instead of 
           //displaying each in its respective div it only displays in the top div
            echo '<span id="voteCount-'.$row['topic_id'].'">'.$this->cleanNumber($row['topic_likes']).'</span>';

            if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){

                echo ' <a href="#" class="downVoteArrow" onclick="downVoteDecrementValue('.$row['topic_id'].');"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>';

            }else{

                echo ' <a href="#" id="loginForm" class="downVoteArrow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>';

            }
```

Here is a picture of what it's doing

[image]

It increments...That part works fine as in the 1st and 2nd example but when I Go to upvote the next value below it, it displays that value in the first location (98 moves up into the 1st location and increments to 99) how can I get the 98 to increment in it's place and not be displayed in the first location?  Thanks again and appreciate all feedback.

Here is the PHP database portion if it comes in handy for anyone who might want to use it:

```
if(isset($_POST['upVoteIncrement'])){

$upVoteIncrement = $_POST['upVoteIncrement'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE topics SET topic_likes = topic_likes+1 WHERE topic_id = :id LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $upVoteIncrement);
$stmt->execute();


$upVote = $conn->prepare('SELECT topic_likes FROM topics WHERE topic_id = :id');
$upVote->bindParam(':id', $upVoteIncrement);
$upVote->execute();
$upVoteCount = $upVote->fetchAll();

if($upVote->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($upVoteCount as $row){

        $up = $row['topic_likes'];
        $results[] = $up;
    }
}
echo json_encode($results);
}

if(isset($_POST['downVoteDecrement'])){

$downVoteDecrement = $_POST['downVoteDecrement'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE topics SET topic_likes = topic_likes-1 WHERE topic_id = :id LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $downVoteDecrement);
$stmt->execute();

$downVote = $conn->prepare('SELECT topic_likes FROM topics WHERE topic_id = :id LIMIT 1');
$downVote->bindParam(':id', $downVoteDecrement);
$downVote->execute();
$downVoteCount = $downVote->fetchAll();

if($downVote->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($downVoteCount as $row){

        $down = $row['topic_likes'];
        $results[] = $down;
    }
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

}

Comment: I deleted my answer as I misread, are all your IDs unique on the page?

Comment: That's ok, yeah they are all unique for each div. What I am thinking is I need to create an array of the response in ajax for the id of the span <span id="voteCount"></span>   <- this is the div that displays the number of votes but only displays the incrementing values in one place.

Comment: Can you post an example of the html? If you click the one that's 163 votes does it also go to the top?

Comment: yep, all of the values go to the top and increment in that one top div. once I refresh the page then they are all updated properly in their respective <divs> here is the line where they are displayed:  echo '<span id="voteCount">'.$this->cleanNumber($row['topic_likes']).'</span>';

Comment: You could give each container a unique ID and when the ajax is called replace the associated container. EG. <td id=vote-"'.$row['topic_id'].'" style="color: #333;"> when you call the ajax make sure it's including the full html for the td and then your ajax  replace would be $('#vote-'+postID).html(response);

Comment: You are genious, or should I say "Second2None"...That worked perfect. Thanks. Just needed to add the postID to the container.